# Running Total with calculated xsl:variables?

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

My accounting-XML contain two separate elements, one just for positive and the other for negative money-values. I want to create a HTML-table using XSL for the incoming and outgoing transfer, PLUS the Running Total for each row. I found the `sum(preceding-sibling::Buchungszeile/Betrag) + Betrag)` which work fine if all elements contain a number. Unfortunately for positive values, the negative element is not 0, but empty and vice versa.

```
<Buchungszeile>
  <Buchungstag>2019-12-05</Buchungstag>
  <Soll-Betrag>100</Soll-Betrag>
  <Haben-Betrag></Haben-Betrag>
</Buchungszeile>
<Buchungszeile>
  <Buchungstag>2019-12-06</Buchungstag>
  <Soll-Betrag></Soll-Betrag>
  <Haben-Betrag>155</Haben-Betrag>
</Buchungszeile>
<Buchungszeile>
  <Buchungstag>2019-12-07</Buchungstag>
  <Soll-Betrag>50</Soll-Betrag>
  <Haben-Betrag></Haben-Betrag>
</Buchungszeile>
```

Problem 1: With the help of a xsl:variable `$betrag` I am able to just display all the money-values in one single HTML-column, the negative ones with a leading "-". But I don't find a way to access this variable for the Running Total `sum()` function.

Problem 2: I don't find a way to generate a new XML-element e.g. `<Betrag>`on the fly containing all the positive and negative values to use for the `sum(preceding-sibling::Buchungszeile/Betrag) + Betrag)`

Problem 3: I don't find a way to access the value of the previous row using `position()`.

Which would be the correct way to reach this result:

```
<table>
 <tr> <td>Buchungstag</td> <td>Betrag</td> <td>Running Total</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td> 2019-12-05</td> <td>  -100</td> <td>         -100</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td> 2019-12-06</td> <td>   155</td> <td>           55</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td> 2019-12-07</td> <td>   -50</td> <td>            5</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an entirely different approach, which not only handles the empty nodes but also avoids the expensive repeated summing of previous siblings values:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
        <tr> 
            <th>Buchungstag</th>
            <th>Betrag</th>
            <th>Running Total</th>
        </tr>
            <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="Buchungszeile"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="prev-balance" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($nodes)">
        <xsl:variable name="node" select="$nodes[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="amount" select="concat('0', $node/Haben-Betrag) - concat('0', $node/Soll-Betrag)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="balance" select="$prev-balance + $amount"/>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$node/Buchungstag"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$amount"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$balance"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="prev-balance" select="$balance"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much fo the fast answer. After some small modifications in my existing XSL (I used a '<xsl:for-each>' loop before to access the <Buchungszeile> elements) your solution works perfect for me.

Comment: Good. Note that `xsl:for-each` is not a "loop" - which is precisely why I did not use it here.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 or later or Saxon-JS 2 or AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later) you could use an accumulator:

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="total"/>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="total" as="xs:decimal" initial-value="0">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Buchungszeile/Soll-Betrag[. castable as xs:decimal]"
        select="$value - xs:decimal(.)"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Buchungszeile/Haben-Betrag[. castable as xs:decimal]"
        select="$value + xs:decimal(.)"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="transaktionen">
      <table class="buchung">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Buchungstag</th>
                  <th>Betrag</th>
                  <th>Running Total</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Buchungszeile">
      <tr>
          <td>{Buchungstag}</td>
          <td>{if (Soll-Betrag castable as xs:decimal) then -xs:decimal(Soll-Betrag) else xs:decimal(Haben-Betrag)}</td>
          <td>{accumulator-after('total')}</td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6P

Comment: Thanks for your lean solution, but I have not yet had any experience with XSLT 3.0 and the XML should be able to be displayed directly with a standard browser, without additional extensions.